# Docker compose ignoring command line arguments

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have the following docker compose file

```bash
version: "3.8"

services:
  local-dev:
    image: solver-dev
    container_name: local-dev
    environment:
      - RUST_LOG=khalani_solver=debug
    command: "local-dev-env"

  intent_book_matchmaker:
    image: solver-dev
    container_name: intent_book_matchmaker
    depends_on:
      - local-dev
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      - PRIVATE_KEY=${PRIVATE_KEY}
      - CONFIG_FILE=/config/with-local.json
      - SEPOLIA_RPC_URL=${SEPOLIA_RPC_URL}
      - SEPOLIA_WS_URL=${SEPOLIA_WS_URL}
      - FUJI_RPC_URL=${FUJI_RPC_URL}
      - FUJI_WS_URL=${FUJI_WS_URL}
      - RUST_LOG=khalani_solver=debug,intentbook-matchmaker=debug
    command: intentbook-matchmaker --private-key $${PRIVATE_KEY} --config-file /config/with-local.json
```

these flags are required by the application to run. I have these in my `.env` flag.

unfortunately , when i run the container, i keep getting this error.

> intent_book_matchmaker    | error: the following required arguments were not provided:
> intent_book_matchmaker    |   --config-file <CONFIG_FILE>
> intent_book_matchmaker    |
> intent_book_matchmaker    | Usage: intentbook-matchmaker --config-file <CONFIG_FILE>
> intent_book_matchmaker    |
> intent_book_matchmaker    | For more information, try '--help'.

I would appreciate pointers on this

Comment: What is in your image's Dockerfile?  (Does the image declare an `ENTRYPOINT` in some form?)

Comment: @DavidMaze this is my entry point : ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "-c"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment you say that your Dockerfile contains

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
```

`sh -c` takes only a single argument.  When Compose splits your `command:` into multiple words, only the first word is processed by `sh -c`.  That's why you see an error that apparently the arguments are missing.

In the Compose file, if `command:` is a list rather than a string, you can manually specify the list of words, and Compose won't try to split it for you.  This can let you force it into a single argument

```yaml
command:
  - intentbook-matchmaker --private-key $${PRIVATE_KEY} --config-file /config/with-local.json
```

I might not set `ENTRYPOINT` in a way that forces `CMD` to be a full command string, but instead specify the `sh -c` wrapper in the Compose file.

```yaml
# (delete the Dockerfile ENTRYPOINT)
command:
  - /bin/sh
  - -c
  - intentbook-matchmaker --private-key $${PRIVATE_KEY} --config-file /config/with-local.json
```

In the setup you show, `$PRIVATE_KEY` is already set in Compose's environment.  You could ask Compose to interpolate the environment variable, instead of using a shell.  Compose can't do much more than simple string substitutions, but that's all you need here.

```yaml
# (delete the Dockerfile ENTRYPOINT)
command: intentbook-matchmaker --private-key ${PRIVATE_KEY} --config-file /config/with-local.json
#                            only one $ here ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Few issues here:

1. You have both `env_file` and `environment` declared. According to the documentation, [if you use both the env_file and environment attribute, environment variables set by environment take precedence.](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/set-environment-variables/#use-the-env_file-attribute) I would recommend choosing one method over another, for consistency.
2. `CONFIG_FILE` seems to be set to a hardcoded path. If that is the case, probably doesn't need to be set as an environmental variable.
3. `$${PRIVATE_KEY}` in your command should be `${PRIVATE_KEY}` (notice the single `$`)
4. And to the root of the problem, it seems that the container image you are using already has an entrypoint configured, so the command argument is being appended to the contents of the entrypoint. You will need to inspect the `solver-dev` image, determine what the entrypoint looks like, and modify the command you provide in your docker compose file.